# Ionic + Account kit phone number = crash on android

Tags: ionic-framework, account-kit

I want to user accountkit on ionic for connection but when i press the button the app is crashing with no errors

Method :

```
(<any>window).AccountKitPlugin.loginWithPhoneNumber({
  useAccessToken: true,
  defaultCountryCode: "IN",
  facebookNotificationsEnabled: true,
}, data => {
(<any>window).AccountKitPlugin.getAccount(
  info => this.userInfo = info,
  err => console.log(err));
});
```

Someone can help me ?

Comment: It's working on a blank app but crash on the real

Answer (score 1):

I also get this error today and waste so much time to find a solution for it. But all question has no answer. Finally, I got a solution that is work for me. I post here for someone who need.

Add this line

```
cordova.system.library.9=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0
```

into platforms/android/project.properties

Hope it is useful

Comment: oh my you saved my damn life partner